# The wallet (which was) stolen is mine

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, syntax, passive-voice

Are any of these grammatically incorrect?

1. ‡The wallet which was stolen is mine.
2. ‡The stolen wallet is mine.
3. ‡‡The wallet stolen is mine.

the one I quoted with ‡‡ is the sentence that my university teacher stated was  grammatically correct ... but I still have my doubts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a noun modifying clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause) (see John Lawler's seminal answer).

Answer (score 2):

All three are correct.

> 1. The wallet which was stolen is mine.
> 2. The stolen wallet is mine.
> 3. The wallet stolen is mine.

Number 1 is a bit long-winded, but is fine. Number 2 is the usual everyday way of saying it. Number 3 is using what's called a [postpositive adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective), an adjective that comes after its noun. In English they are usually confined to poetic use, but they are still grammatical. I would expand it to:

> The wallet **that was** stolen is mine.

This is almost identical to sentence number 1.

In *The men injured were taken to hospital*, you can replace *injured* with *injured in the accident*, at which point you can't put it before the noun.

> **The injured in the accident men were taken to hospital* is wrong
>
> *The men injured in the accident were taken to hospital* is right

In **The many boys angry refused to stay*, *angry* is not a past participle, whereas both *stolen* and *injured* are. We could also say:

> The wallet stolen by the monkey is mine.

but not:

> *The stolen by the monkey wallet is mine.

Other examples:

> time wasted
>
> document attached

Comment: I've asked for clarification on the POS of say 'injured' in 'The men injured were taken to hospital'. A strong argument against it being a postpositive adjective is that 'The men injured were taken to hospital' and 'The injured men were taken to hospital' are far from being exact synonyms. Certainly prenominal 'injured' modifies the noun ('The unfortunate / sick / injured / wounded / ... men were taken to hospital'), but in 'The men injured were taken to hospital'  there is (probably by association with 'The men who were / had been injured were taken to hospital') a (perhaps ...

Comment: not completely overt) referencing of the act/s or accident/s causing the injuries. Lone adjectives typically can't remain after the noun after whiz-deletion ('The many boys who were angry refused to stay.' / *'The many boys angry refused to stay.')

Answer (score 0):

" the wallet stolen is mine" is grammatically incorrect
you can write- "the wallet which was stolen is mine"

Comment: Is 'The men injured were all taken to hospital' grammatically incorrect?

Comment: If you provided some rationale and evidence your answer might be comprehensible (though still mistaken); as it is it will probably be deleted as worthless personal opinion.

Comment: If you think it's incorrect, please explain sentences like ["...the girls abducted...were returned to their families."](https://www.unicef.org/media/media_102759.html)

Comment: @stangdon: How do you explain the grammaticality of “Me is” in the sentence “***Me*** is a pronoun”?   My point is, you’re cheating.   The sentence you linked to says “the girls abducted *on 19 February 2018 from a school in Dapchi, Yobe state, northeast Nigeria* were returned to their families.” (I added emphasis to the part you elided.)   As [John Lawler explains](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/50962/26083#50971 "What is a noun modifying clause?"), this is an example of ***Whiz*-Deletion** (short for “the girls ***who were*** abducted …”)   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … and in such cases “phrases can't appear in front of the noun, but must follow it” (e.g., “Bill is a man happy to see you.” is OK but “*Bill is a happy to see you man.” is not). So, arguably, “the girls abducted _on 19 February 2018_” is not the same construct as “the girls abducted”. Besides, the fact that a sentence is posted somewhere on the Internet does not prove that it is grammatically correct.

Comment: @Scott - If my example is "cheating" because it's whiz-deletion, how is "the wallet stolen is mine" NOT an example of whiz-deletion?  It's "the wallet *which was* stolen is mine".

Comment: @stangdon: I thought the “me is” example would have made it clear. Your comparison was cheating because you quoted a sentence, but left out part that makes a difference (e.g., Richard Nixon said “I am … a crook.”) The sentence you quoted was a whiz-deletion where the text left after deletion is a phrase (and not just a single word; e.g., a past participle), and yet you suggest that it should follow the same patterns as a sentence where the text left after deletion is just a single word (and not a phrase).